# After visiting Fiji (on the dateline), and then going back in time, can't access github.com

Tags: google-chrome

There seems to be a problem in Chrome if one switches timezones to go to the prior day.I get the following error. Any workaround besides using Safari for some websites? And yes, my time is correctly set.

Should I be concerned about some virus if I was using a hotel wifi previously and am seeing this message?

I'm on OSX 10.9.4.

"Your connection is not private. Attackers might be trying to steal your information"

The fix of this is described here:

https://blog.digicert.com/expired-intermediate-certificate/

and

https://superuser.com/a/788547/103418

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From what I know there's nothing to worry if you indeed had to change your computer clock (and did so rather than changing timezones only?).

As you can see in the footer of the message, the actual error is an invalid date/time, which typically means there's something wrong with your PC clock (hey, something ringing? :)).

Make sure your PC clock is indeed correct. If you travel to a different time zone, update the PC's current time zone, **not** the actual time.

If your time/date are correct again, clear your browser cache and cookies just to be sure, and everything should be working fine again.

Comment: I did try clearing the browser cache and cookies for the last 4 weeks and that did not work. I suspect the problem is going back dates due to the timezone switch.

Comment: But your PC's clock is set properly? For example, right now it should be 8:33 AM on the 28th July, if you set your time zone to UTC/GMT (without DST).

Comment: Time on Mac is set automatically based on IP and it's correct. I'm having problems with some some other sites, but not most https are OK. And Safari is OK.

Comment: Very odd, and this is a permanent issue, even if you try to reload the page several times? Also are you trying to open the http or the https version of Github?

Comment: https://blog.digicert.com/expired-intermediate-certificate/ -- Apparently a problem for many!