# digicert secure server ca signed by unknown authority mac os

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Related to:
[Why won't OS X trust GitHub's SSL certificate?](https://superuser.com/questions/605900/why-wont-os-x-trust-githubs-ssl-certificate/788547#788547)

Why when I download this certificate and drag/drop into my Keychain on OSX, it shows as

I downloaded from here: https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm

[image].

This leads to a number of sites giving security warnings, such as linkedin.com.

What sort of action should I take?

I tried deleting the certificate and then going to LinkedIn.com and I got this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "DigiCert Secure Server CA" is clearly marked as an intermediate certificate at the page of digicert you referenced. You need to download the root certificate, not an intermediate certificate. You get this warning because this intermediate certificate is signed by the root certificate "DigiCert Global Root CA" which you did not import into the keychain.

Comment: Brilliant. That was it.